# Visual Studio 2012 Performance Analysis failing to load symbol file

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

I have used the Visual Studio 2012 Performance Analysis to profile my C++ code for a long time, but recently when I try to use it seems to be failing to load the symbols as I get this error when I try to view the details

> Matching symbols could not be found. Choose the 'Symbol Settings..'
>   link to add the symbol file location and then reload the report.

I have visited `Options -> Debugging -> Symbols` but I don't know what I need to add so that the symbols load correctly.

Currently in that menu `Symbol file (.pdf) locations:` has one option available in it and it called `Microsoft Symbol Servers` and it is selected. In the `Cashe symbols in this directory:` I can see it is being set in a temp folder but when I go that folder I see it is empty.

What do I need to add so that the symbols load correctly?

Comment: Are you able to reach `http://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols`?  That's the MS public symbol server.

Comment: Sorry, forgot to update this. This is a known issue in VS2012 and Windows8.1 and Microsoft has either fixed it by now or will in future update. Here is the link - social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/0a244be1-9bf9-484f-a7ac-b4e10e18b6e4/visual-studio-2012-performance-analysis-failing-to-load-symbol-file?forum=vsdebug

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I asked this question on MSDN and I was told that this is a known issue with Visual Studio 2012 and Windows 8.1. Microsoft has either by now fixed it or will fix it in a future update. [Here is a link to the MSDN question.](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/0a244be1-9bf9-484f-a7ac-b4e10e18b6e4/visual-studio-2012-performance-analysis-failing-to-load-symbol-file?forum=vsdebug)

Comment: Is there any workaround for this?  This is a huge problem for us right now.

Comment: I just started using VS2013 and it doesn't have that issue. You can also just go back to W8 but that is not easy option.

Comment: I wish I had access to VS2013 and maybe I can get my work to get that soon.  I'm not reverting the OS back just because of one feature.  For the moment, I'm using Redgate's Performance Profiler trial.  It works pretty well.

Answer (score 1):

make sure you build your project with .pdb files and add these to the list of symbol locations (possible library pdb's as well). I know this should be a comment, but i don't have the reputation for it yet :(

Comment: Sorry, forgot to update this. This is a known issue in VS2012 and Windows8.1 and Microsoft has either fixed it by now or will in future update. Here is the link - social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/0a244be1-9bf9-484f-a7ac-b4e10e18b6e4/visual-studio-2012-performance-analysis-failing-to-load-symbol-file?forum=vsdebug